# Ublox Neo 6m GPS with Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, gps

I'm trying to use Ublox Neo 6m GPS module in my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, running Raspbian Jessie for my project.

I've connected Vcc 3.3V to GPS's VCC, Ground to Ground, RX to TXD and TX to RXD.

Then I tried configuring the connection by following some tutorials, but none of them are working.

I tried removing `console = ttyAMA0,115200` from /boot/cmdline.txt and installed gpsd.

While running the command `cgps -s` I'm getting GPS timeout.

This is my first time working with a RPI. Any detailed tutorial of my configuration would be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

`cgps` doesn't communicate with your gps.  It talks to the `gpsd` daemon, which is responsible for communicating with your GPS.  Some diagnostic steps you can take:

- Does `/dev/ttyAMA0` exist on your system? It may be called `/dev/ttyS0` if you're on a Pi 3 with a recent kernel.  See [this document](https://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection) for more information.
- Can you connect to the GPS manually?  The document linked in the previous bullet point has instructions for using `screen` to do that.
- Are you running `gpsd`?  And is it configured with the correct serial port?

Comment: I tried ttys0 and same thing occurred. Can you please tell me how can I determine if my GPS is connected or not? lsusb doesn't show any specific device that can be my GPS module

Comment: Your device isn't connected via USB, so of course that won't show up in the output of `lsusb`. Did you read the "RPi Serial Connection" document? That has pretty much all the information you need to interact with serial devices. If that doesn't help I don't have much I can add.